# Euler's method approximating differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory

We have been told that $u'(t)= u(t)$ and $u(0)=1$
from this information we can conclude that $u(t) =e^x$

Show that 
$ u_k =(1+h)^k,k=0,1,...$  is an approximation for $u(kh) $
using Euler's method

My current thoughts are that h is the interval by which we increment, but I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

$$
u_k = u(k h) ~~~~\mbox{for}~~~ k = 0, 1, \cdots
$$

Euler's method can be expressed as

$$
u_{k + 1} = u_k + hu'_k = u_k + h (u_k) = (1 + h)u_k
$$

You can easily figure out the solution to this expression

\begin{eqnarray}
u_1 &=& (1 + h)u_0 \\
u_2 &=& (1 + h)u_1 = (1 + h)^2u_0 \\
u_3 &=& (1 + h)u_2 = (1 + h)^3u_0 \\
&\vdots& \\
u_k &=& (1 + h)u_{k - 1} = (1 + h)^k u_0
\end{eqnarray}

which reduces to $u_k = (1 + h)^k$ if $u_0 = u(t = 0) = 1$