# How can I use Euler's Method in order to find the value of a constant k given the differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, eulers-method

So, I am trying to attempt part b of this problem using my answer from part a. I just want to confirm if I did part a correctly and how I can do part b?

[image]

Comment: Related : [How do I find the values of the constants for which $y = ax + b +e^{cx}$ is a solution to the differential equation given](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3599402). A solution was already provided for part (a). What ideas do you have about part (b)? You need to show some effort. See eg [Euler's method approximating differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2301205)

Comment: I pretty sure I actually can do part b, but I'm skeptical of part a. I'm not sure if it is right.

Comment: However, I will try to see what I can come up with in part b.

Comment: ok, so I tried the Euler method and solved for k and I got k = -7/9. Is there a way I can check to make sure this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

There are two possibilities :

with Euler after, $\; $
at $ x=0 $, the equation is
$$f'(0)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=2f(0)+1$$

thus $ k=-\frac 13.$

Euler before, $\; $
at $ x=1 $,  gives

$$f'(1)=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=3+2f(1)+1$$
hence
$ k=- 4$.

Comment: So I tried to do the Euler Method and I got k = -7/9. However, I am not sure if this is correct. Is there a way for me to check my solution?

Comment: I plugged in -7/9 in the Euler Method and I got f(1) = 0. So I think I have my solution